# Making sure duplicate model wont be added to collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a button on my screen that is pre-populating user info into a collection I have set up. This is working...a little too well in fact. Every time the user hits the button it adds a new model. To prevent the user from adding more than one model to this collection I would like to check to make sure that an attribute inside the collection is not the same of what I'm trying to pass in. If that makes any sense.

My object looks like this

```
var object = { 
    First: first,
    Second: second
};
```

and I'm inserting it like so

```
this.app.user.get(type).add(object); //My type is what collection is being passed to it
```

I'm then grabbing the 'Second' attribute from each model in the property

```
var dup = this.app.user.get(type).map(function(model){
    return model.get('Second');
});
```

What I'm having trouble doing is seeing my property addressTo (which is just a string) is equal to anything within that dup object. I've tried a few things, but nothing has gotten me very far and just ended up breaking more things.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When you wan't to use the array you have, you could use underscore to check if the array contains the element (underscore is a core-dependency of backbone, so you have it already ;)):

```
_.contains(dup, obj.addressTo)
```

Otherwise you could also use the collection directly:

```
collection.where({ 'Second': obj.addressTo }).length > 0
```

Comment: The obj, is that a variable or does it have to be there? I'm asking because it's telling me it's not defined.

Comment: I named it `obj`, cause your `object` "variable" is a preserved keyword (it's the type of each object).

Comment: It's a preserved keyword in backbone? Even if that variable was changed an if statement with it's always returning false. Is that because the 'dup' is an object and the addressTo is a string?

Comment: `object` is a preserved keyword in JavaScript. Backbone.js is only a framework. I will only say - you can't name a variable `object`!

Comment: I'm not naming anything object... I was just not aware that adressTo was reserved, I've never heard of it being reserved before and have used it many times. Regardless though I tried an if statement if( _.contains(dup, addressedTo) === false) and it seems to be always returning false and I am trying to figure out why so I  can fixz this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to [define an id property](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute) of the model and Backbone will care about duplicates for you. [Here is](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add) more details about `add` method.

And small example how it works:

```
var Type = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute: 'Second'
});
var types = new Backbone.Collection([{ First: 1, Second: 11 }], {model: Type})

types.add(new Type({ First: 1, Second: 11 }));
types.add(new Type({ First: 2, Second: 22 }));
types.add(new Type({ First: 2, Second: 22 }));

console.log(types.length); // 2
```

Comment: I don't want to add it as a new collection though. I'[m updating a previous collection

Comment: @zazvorniki, then imagine that `types` is a reference to your existing collection. Here is only one limitation - your collection should be created with `model` option which describes `idAttribute`

Comment: I don't think this is going to work because the models I'm throwing into the collection are coming from another model and I cannot alter those because the id is dynamic depending on where I'm throwing it.